# Multiple Line Header with Multiple horizontal lines

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I'm trying to use `fancyhdr` to make a multiple line header with the following format:

```
Left Header     Center Header
--------------------------------------------
                                 Right Header
                      ----------------------
```

Where the `---` represent a horizontal line.

Basically I would like the left header to be a line under the other two, plus a separating line between both headers.

Is there a way to do so using redefining the `headrule` command?

Comment: Welcome! Please post a small, complete document illustrating the problem you are having implementing this. At the same time, please clarify your question. Do you really want the left header to be repeated below right?

Comment: What content should be placed in the `Left Header`, `Center Header` and `Right Header`, respectively?

Comment: @Werner There should be an Image on `Left Header`, some text on `Center Header` and section name on `Right Header`, still my problem is with the middle horizontal line and the right justified  horizontal end line

Comment: @cfr No, it was a mistake, I meant  `Right Header`

Comment: Please provide some code. Not only does it make it easier to answer, it also makes it much less likely that the answer won't actually work for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a lot you can do in the headers. I've set the `Left Header` as-is, while the `Center Header` and `Right Header` is set using a `tabular` of fixed width. The advantage of using a `tabular` is that you can use its `\hline`s for rules:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr,lipsum}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
\fancyhead[L]{Left Header}
\fancyhead[C]{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}p{\textwidth}@{}}
  \hfill Center Header \hfill \strut \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}}
\fancyhead[R]{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}p{.5\textwidth}@{}}
  \strut \\
  \strut \hfill \leftmark \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\setlength{\headheight}{25pt}

\begin{document}

\section{First section}
\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

Horizontal alignment is achieved using appropriately-placed`\hfill`s, while vertical alignment is achived by the insertion of `\strut`s.

The `\headheight` adjustment depends on the contents. In my case [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) suggested to it to be at least `24.4pt`, so I set it to `25pt`.